# Website HTTPS certificate

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https, redirect

Since I've been adding an ssl certificate today and everything worked out good i'm still facing one problem.

i'm having insecure http which makes the green bar on top of the page go away. I want all my content on my website to load from https.

```
 <img href="http://...."></img>
```

Needs to go to a https link for my images. I know I could manually adjust them all but I'm using plugins which load their own content from http links. I tried .htaccess files and i am also using them to force https on my website. But img tags don't see to change their href link to https.

Answer (score 1):

> I know i could manually adjust them all but i'm using plugins which
>   load their own content from http links.

If you already know the above restriction, the the following requirement would **never be** satisfied.

> I'm having insecure http which makes the green bar on top of the page
>   go away.

The green bar is there **because** everything is being served over *HTTPS*, including your own calls, third-party plugins, any hidden frames/scripts/stylesheets etc.

You'll need to manually update your `src="http://` (`img` tag uses `src` or `srcset` attribute and not `href`) links to point to `https` URLs. Even if your htaccess is set to forward HTTP calls to HTTPS, the browser sees an `HTTP` link, and turns your green bar to yellow (or red)!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#upgrade-insecure-requests might help with some browsers